# Memory not Unloading

Tags: memory, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf

One of our PC's is not unloading it's memory during certain tasks. The main one is when they choose to print a file to PDF.

- Select File
- Open in Adobe Acrobat
- Print to PDF
- Save and Close

This is what happens with the memory during this process:

[image: Large spikes in Memory Usage]

This Memory usage goes from Startup > Print one file to PDF (First blue box) > Idle > Print one file to PDF (Second blue box)

- A similar occurrence happened while attempting to resize a file in Paint (reduce it to half size).
- The files that are generally dealt with are .tiff files.
- Each .tiff file is ~500 KB, some might be larger, some smaller, but within ~200 KB of each other. Very rarely there might be a file that is ~1 MB.

I have re-installed Adobe Acrobat in an attempt to fix this, but it has had no effect on the processes.

**EDIT:** I should note the this is causing severe performance problems. After the second Print to PDF, the PC slows right down, simple tasks (opening a program like paint or word) takes minutes, and if they wanted to Print to PDF again, **what might normally take 2-3 minutes, now takes 30 minutes for a single file.**

This process (as stated above) would normally take a few minutes to complete multiple Print to PDF's at once, but now, after completing 2 or 3, takes half an hour to print one file to PDF. Sometimes, if a file preview becomes unavailable (taking too long to load the preview in Folder Explorer), it will simply print an empty/blank PDF.

**How can I get the memory to unload, or even stop building, so I can print multiple PDF's like I used to?**

Comment: There are various tools to prove a more indepeth of your memory usage.  Have you used those tools to verify the memory belongs to Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: No, I haven't. As I stated this also happens when attempting to resize files in Paint, so I would believe it's not to do with Acrobat alone

Comment: @Ben Yep, it's just normal OS behavior. No reason to make memory free just to create extra work when we want to use the memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the problem is, that the memory *is* needed. As I stated above in my edit, the PC used to be able to do multiple with little to no issue, and now it struggles with 3, one after the other.

Comment: @Ben - Before I vote to reopen this question.  I have a question myself.  Have you simply reloaded this problem computer's image?

Comment: @Ramhound Are you referring to the file (the .tiff) or something else?

Comment: I am basically asking if you have tried to reinstall Windows.

Comment: No, we haven't gone that far. This has started happening on another PC as well, so that might affect the judgement

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the processes in Task Manager and make sure you select Show processes for all users.  Also consider posting a screenshot from something like RAMMap (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700229.aspx)

Comment: @Ben You edited your question to a completely different one. It was about memory being used, with no mention of any performance problems.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think you'll find that the contents of the original question (before it was closed) has been unchanged. I have just added additional information.

Comment: @Ben The original question didn't mention any abnormal behavior and asked how to induce abnormal behavior. The edit mentioned abnormal behavior and asked how to induce normal behavior. Calling that unchanged is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well I apologise for the confusion. The point of this question was to find a way to deal with the memory filling up so quickly, effectively stopping any further use of the machine. As I said, the process is slowing all computer functionality down after 2 Print to PDF's. Originally it could do this for up to 10, maybe more. The fact that this is occurring after only 2, seems abnormal, and should probably not be happening.

Comment: @Ben It's not the memory filling up that's stopping further use of the machine. Memory being full is perfectly normal. The only things you can do with memory are use it or waste it. You can't save it for later. Read my answer again because it seems you still don't get it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz having no RAM free is normal and good, but having no RAM+swap free is a problem, and it looks like that's what's happening to Ben, though he hasn't shown the screen shot yet.  Ben please do edit in James's request, and I'd be curious to see the columns Working Set and Memory.

Comment: @Ben I don't doubt David's answer.  However, Does this behavior happen with any pdf document of any size.  If its happening with a 1 page pdf document thats a problem, if its happening with a 500 page document thats an entirely other story.

Comment: Hi guys, I have constructed a new question regarding this issue, and hopefully I have added all the information required. http://superuser.com/questions/908355/computer-slowing-down-after-several-print-to-pdf-requests

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior. Free memory is entirely wasted so modern operating systems do everything they can to avoid having free physical memory.

Consider some memory that's in use and contains data read from, or written to, the disk. Consider what happens if the operating system makes that memory free:

1. That takes effort, so there's an immediate performance cost to making it free.
2. If the system needs the information that was in that memory, it has to read it from disk instead of just re-using it.
3. If that memory isn't used soon, making it free has no beneficial effect.
4. If that memory is used soon, the effort of making it free has to be undone anyway.

So making memory free is all bad. It's only done when free memory is absolutely needed for some reason or the memory contains information that can't possibly be used. Modern operating systems transition memory directly from one use to another without having to make it free in the meantime, which is a win all around.

If you're thinking "I want that memory free now so I can use it later", forget it. You can use it now *and* use it later. Using the memory now is absolutely free -- there's no painful tradeoff to be made here.

If you have an actual performance problem, tell us about it. But having memory in use is perfectly normal.

Comment: What you are talking about is **cached** memory, but as his original screenshot shows, only 282MB of his 8GB of RAM is being used that way. The important figure to look at is **Available** RAM which is barely 5% and dangerously low - it's not surprising that performance was affected. Available memory is not the same as free memory and includes cached memory that can be reallocated.

Comment: @James The system's cached memory display only shows this happening at kernel level. It happens at application level as well. In fact, Windows has specific applicaiton-level caching systems (like SuperFetch).

Comment: @James Also, drivers do caching at kernel level that's not cached block device pages, which also doesn't get counted under cached. For example, NTFS metadata caches are true caches and can be released if there's memory pressure, but they're not counted as cached.