# Computer slowing down after several Print to PDF requests

Tags: memory, printing, adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf

I recently asked about [Memory not unloading](https://superuser.com/questions/896008/memory-not-unloading) and was helped by the answers I've got, but recently understood the problem is something different, so I'm posting a new question.

The problem is that when a user attempts to Print a .tiff file to PDF, regardless of size it would seem, after ~2-5 (give or take) attempts the PC performing the task slows down exponentially. This results in the Print to PDF task taking >30 mins for a single file.

As per requested in my previous question, here are some screenshots of the Task Manager and Processes during the task.

Print1: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0eZV.png]

Print 2:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsvUl.png]

Print 3: (Started slowing down. Print took ~10 minutes)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLfzo.png]

Print 4: (Print took ~20 minutes)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKtO4.png]

Print 5: (Print took ~25 minutes)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlAlZ.png]

Print 6: (Print took ~25 minutes, printed a blank PDF. Preview pane had also crashed)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYJrN.png]

Print 6 (Retry): (Print took ~25 minutes, printed a blank PDF again. Preview pane still not working)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxpE9.png]

Also, when the user attempted to move the screen dumps from their desktop to the shared directory, an error popped up saying

> There is not enough Memory to complete this operation".

After which, their PC crashed entirely, and they had to reset the PC to move the files successfully.

Comment: You never indicated which pdf viewer your using nor the version of that program.

Comment: @Ramhound the program(s) used I am uncertain of. They Right-Click the file, choose "Print", wich opens a Windows Printer(?) They choose "Adobe PDF". This is how they print to PDF.

Comment: The main PDF programs we use are Adobe. Reader and Acrobat XI are both installed on the machines

Comment: What happens if you copy the file to your computer instead of using a network share?

Comment: @ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ It doesn't make a difference

Comment: So which one, causes this problem, Reader or Acrobat? If you can't tell us go find out

Comment: @Ben I tried looking at this but my arch. is different so rather than abandon possibilities: Suggestions seen online for similar problems included: 1."Excessive transparency" causes PDF conversion to choke (it should be at least TIF->PS->PDF and not directly done by the  PDF print conversion, which crashes). 2.TIFs weren't necessary for another engineer, JPGs (probably at high fidelity and for print shops) were business-appropriate...for them. 3.TIFs are inefficient with respect to original dimensions; if you don't use whole canvas it's still processed as if you did. Alternative idea next.

Comment: Leaving the troubleshooting with better-equipped commenters, to address the need to print while troubleshooting: some TIF to PDF converters from questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5152451/3981745   which mentions IrfanView, XnView, LibTiff.net and Ghostscript (gs) as possibilities. Of these, gs may most reliably get the conversion done but can't advise that ahead of troubleshooting your primary issue due to more complex Windows setup. Links for all are at the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor memory usage it is better to use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
If you print to `Adobe PDF` printer with Adobe Acrobat (not just Reader) installed it means that you are using a virtual printer created by Adobe Acrobat.

From that pictures you have posted it is not clear, which process is leaking memory, which seems to be your problem. Under some circumstances a process may fail to unallocate memory which is a problem called memory leak. When it happens many times it may slow down computer making it unresponsive.

You must find in Process Explorer which process has increased memory usage after every print - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set). It will probably be some exe installed with Acrobat. Then you can try to kill the process after every print and see if it gets better.

With a question like this you should also specify your exact Acrobat version (not only XI but 11.xx.xx.xx, it should be somewhere in Help menu - System information).

See [this link in Adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1675284) - try to update your Adobe Acrobat or install other software like PDFCreator etc.